# Eclipse Build Path Error (Java SE 8)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swing

I'm trying to execute a very simple program, but Eclipse is not able to pull the javax.swing library.

Code below:

import javax.swing.*;

public class FirstGUI {
    String fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Number");

}

I have watched many tutorials and read all related articles on stackoverflow related to this, but I am still getting this error:

```
- The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced 
 from required .class files
```

I have followed/tried all the following steps:

-Ensured that in Project -> Properties-> Java Build Path -> Libraries tab, "JRE System Library [Java SE 8 (MacOS X Default] has populated. If I click the downward pointing arrow, I see all the .jar files in that library. I had doubts that the javax.swing library could be missing from here, but am I mistaken?? I had just downloaded the newest Java SDK:

Last login: Sun May 22 14:38:17 on ttys000
Christophers-MacBook-Pro:~ christopherveizaga$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
Christophers-MacBook-Pro:~ christopherveizaga$

Further:

-Project -> Properties -> Builders -> Java Builder is checked
-When creating the new project, I made sure to select "New Java Project"
-In Eclipse-> Preferences, I have compiler compliance level set to 1.7 (Should it be something different?)

-In Eclipse-> Preferences -> Installed JRE's , "JRE System Library [Java SE 8 (MacOS X Default]" is showing and checked off.

ALSO, I was able to create a very simple GUI using JFrame instead, and was able to run the code with success! I had a very basic  Why would JFrame work but it's more basic "relative" (JOptionPane) not work (given it was part of the same workspace, project)??? This leads me to believe that the Library has an incomplete set of .jar files, though I could be wrong.

I have deleted and re-installed Eclipse 3 times now (each time trying something different when setting it up), still no dice. I wouldn't have taken the time to ask you guys this but I literally do not know what to do. Because of this damned error, I cannot continue my Java studies and its driving me mad!

Thank you all in advanced. I apologize for the n00b-ness of this question, but like I said, I have run out of options at this point.

-Chris

Answer (score 0):

I think It's an installation problem. Possibly missing files, but more likely some old files that are sitting in the classpath somewhere and masking the Java 8 versions. I would formally uninstall all Java versions, then manually search & destroy all java-related directories, and delete the classpath variables, then download and re-install JDK 8 from scratch. Also if you are using an IDE that may have some old Java version code associated with it, so I would delete & download/re-install that as well.

Comment: Dude, thank you so much. I completely deleted all my Java files and IDE, then started over again from scratch. I figured out that it was when I downloaded and installed Java 8, Java 6 libraries were not overwritten and still being pulled. This caused the massive headache.

Answer (score -1):

Even I faced the similar issue. I replaced the JDK 1.8 System Library with 1.6 and it worked for me.

Kind Regards,
Vishnu